# Finding Similar Binary Sequences

Tags: r, math, statistics

Consider the following data set:

```
id = c(rep("aa", 3), rep("bb", 3), rep("cc", 3))
item = rep(c("run", "jump", "clap"), 3)
day = paste0('Day',1:5)

df = data.frame(id, item)
df[,day] <- c(rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
              rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
              rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
              rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
              rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
              rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
              rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
              rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
              rbinom(5, 1, 0.5)
              )
```

Which yields this:

```
  id item Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5
1 aa  run    0    1    0    0    0
2 aa jump    0    1    0    1    0
3 aa clap    0    0    0    0    0
4 bb  run    0    0    1    1    1
5 bb jump    1    1    0    1    1
6 bb clap    0    1    0    1    1
7 cc  run    1    1    1    1    1
8 cc jump    0    1    1    1    1
9 cc clap    0    1    0    1    0
```

I would like to determine which of the three subjects (aa, bb, cc) have similar patterns with regard to their daily clapping, running, and jumping habits.

Am I looking for some sort of clustering method?  One thing I have tried is to separate out each binary sequence and turn them into 5 character strings and then sort.  This provides a decent visual, but I'm looking for something more programmatic and less manual.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `daisy` from the `cluster` package with Manhattan distance.

```
set.seed(1)
df[,day] <- c(rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
          rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
          rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
          rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
          rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
          rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
          rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
          rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), 
          rbinom(5, 1, 0.5)
          )
df
  id item Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5
1 aa  run    0    0    0    0    1
2 aa jump    0    0    1    1    0
3 aa clap    1    0    1    0    1
4 bb  run    1    1    0    0    0
5 bb jump    0    0    1    1    1
6 bb clap    1    1    0    0    1
7 cc  run    1    0    0    0    1
8 cc jump    1    1    0    1    1
9 cc clap    1    1    0    1    1
```

We will compare the three subjects by run, jump, and clap.

```
require(cluster)

lapply(split(df, df$item), function(xx) {
    xx <- data.frame(xx[, -c(1, 2)], row.names=xx$id)
    daisy(xx, metric="manhattan")
})

$clap
Dissimilarities :
   aa bb
bb  2   
cc  3  1

Metric :  manhattan 
Number of objects : 3

$jump
Dissimilarities :
   aa bb
bb  1   
cc  4  3

Metric :  manhattan 
Number of objects : 3

$run
Dissimilarities :
   aa bb
bb  3   
cc  1  2
```

Higher pairwise numbers mean more dissimilar.  For example, pair **aa/bb** for *run* has the number 3, which is the sum of the absolute value of the differences for each day.

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  I applied this to my actual data set (which has a couple thousand "day" columns and far more zeros than ones) and compared the pairwise numbers with a visualization of the data.  Manhattan and Euclidean distance metrics were not behaving as I had hoped.  The "Gower" metric, however seems to be getting me close.  Thank you for the tip!